# Access using ExceL VBA to format data as Excel Table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

See this [question](http://Sub%20A_SelectAllMakeTable()). It shows a solution for formatting excel data as a table in Excel.

The code is

```
  Sub A_SelectAllMakeTable()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
End Sub
```

I am trying to use this code in Access VBA where I create an Excel output file with Access data then I want to format it similarly. Here is my code.

```
Dim objXL As Object
Dim objWorkbook As Object
Dim objWorkSheet As Object
Dim sourcefilepath As String
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range

Set objXL = New Excel.Application
objXL.Application.Visible = False

sourcefilepath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\CF Break Report " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xls"
Set objWorkbook = objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=sourcefilepath)
Set objWorkSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("_400_CF_BREAK_LOG")

Set rng = objWorkSheet.Range(Range("A1"), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
Set tbl = objWorkSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
```

Update: The line that is failing is

```
   Set rng = objWorkSheet.Range(Range("A1"), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
```

With the error "application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: closing " try that

Comment: it was closed. Copy to this website didn't work. Sorry, will update

Comment: Insert a break point just before the line and see what the tablestyle is.  It doesn't get skipped if it doesn't exist, so it may error, but you may have error trapping skipping it

Comment: I figured it out. its most likely because I am using an .xls format instead of .xlsm format

Comment: nvm disregard the previous comment.

Comment: is ActiveCell on the same sheet as objWorksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`Set rng = objWorkSheet.Range(objWorkSheet.Range("A1"), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))`

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer hidden away [here](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=288146)

```
With xlWB.Sheets("Summary")
Set rng = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
End With
Set tbl = xlWS.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
tbl.ShowTotals = True
```